# Управление длиной path в SVG с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, css, svg, path

[Ассоциация с SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779990/manipulate-svg-path-length-with-jquery/24782696#24782696)

Как я могу регулировать длину голубой линии со 100% до 70%?

```js
setCircleTo(70);

function setCircleTo(percent)
{
    // percent   
    // $('#test').attr('d','') 
}
```

```css
#p0 {
  color: #0074c4;
  left: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72px;
}
#p100 {
  color: #0074c4;
  left: 240px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 144px;
}
```

```html
<div id="p0">0%</div>
<div id="p100">100%</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
    <path fill="none" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" stroke="#0074c4" d="M80,80 A80,80 0 1,180.61117636732928,100.45116865416591" stroke-width="3" id="test"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/24779990/7394871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ заключается в использовании свойств `stroke-dasharray`.

```html
function setCircleTo(percent)
{
    var path = $('#test').get(0);
    var pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
    var adjustedLen = percent * pathLen / 100;
    path.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', adjustedLen+' '+pathLen);
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7FP3J/12/)

Ответил: **Paul LeBeau**

Comment: Если вызвать setCircleTo(100), то выглядит вот так: http://prntscr.com/e6v5av